# Are the Lips wireless microphones for Xbox 360 compatible with Guitar Hero and Rock Band games?

Tags: xbox-360, rock-band, guitar-hero, lips

If it's some, but not all,  which ones (other than the early GH games which have no singing)?

Comment: maybe I should go home and jump on my xbox to find out ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [XBox 360 wireless microphone](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/390/xbox-360-wireless-microphone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have the latest Rock Band 2 title update -- this installs automatically if you're connected to Xbox Live.

Beatles Rock Band and Guitar Hero: Metallica were the first titles to support the wireless mic, anything released after that should support them out of the box as a matter of course.

Answer (score 1):

Guitar Hero 5 was the first Guitar Hero game with support for the Lips mics. Last I heard Rock Band 2 was getting the update to use Lips mics but I don't remember hearing if it actually came out or not.